# angular return sum of variables shows errors

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a cart. Now i want to show a total of the cart using the folowing:

```
$scope.cartSum = function () {
  tot = parseInt($rootScope.cartTotal)+parseInt($scope.resData.restaurant_delivery_charge);
  return tot.toFixed(2);
};
```

html:

```
<div style="float:right;width:20%;text-align:right">
  <span class="pull-left">€ </span>
  <span class="pull-right">&nbsp; {{cartSum()}}
</div>
```

it works, it shows a sum. But for some reason my console shows the following error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$interpolate/interr?p0=%C2%A0%20%7B%7…20Cannot%20read%20property%20'restaurant_delivery_charge'%20of%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:6:453
    at Object.n (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:71:362)
    at g.$digest (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:96:240)
    at g.$apply (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:99:100)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:108:229
    at e (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:33:182)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:36:388 angular.js:8296
2Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$interpolate/interr?p0=%C2%A0%20%7B%7…20Cannot%20read%20property%20'restaurant_delivery_charge'%20of%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:6:453
    at Object.n (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:71:362)
    at g.$digest (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:96:240)
    at g.$apply (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:99:100)
    at k (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:65:98)
    at C (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:68:486)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t.onreadystatechange (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.min.js:69:466)
```

//EDIT: wrapped it to only run when res.data is not undefines... no error now

```
  if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.resData)) {
    tot1 = parseFloat($rootScope.cartTotal);
    tot2 = parseFloat($scope.resData.restaurant_delivery_charge);
    t = tot1+tot2;
    return t.toFixed(2);
```

}

Comment: format of numbers are 0.00

Comment: What is `$scope.resData`, is it set?  `cartSum()` runs when the view is loaded, if you have an ajax call to set `$scope.resData`, when you may want to make sure it finishes first or return something else if it is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owen is right, try this:

```
$scope.cartSum = function () {
  if($scope.resData===undefined || $scope.resData.restaurant_delivery_charge===undefined ||  $rootScope.cartTotal===undefined) return "";
  tot = parseInt($rootScope.cartTotal)+parseInt($scope.resData.restaurant_delivery_charge);
  return tot.toFixed(2);
};
```

And you will see that you won't get that error in the console.

What it's happening is that the first time that angular tries to render some of the properties that you are using in your `cartSum` function are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is saying that it cannot read the property `restaurant_delivery_charge` because `$scope.resData` is undefined. Make sure the object `$scope.resData` is defined before trying to assign a property to it.

Comment: it is defined, also... this code works... it shows the sum.. so it knows the data.. otherwise it would not work

Comment: Have you tried using the latest stable 1.2.x version instead of an old release candidate?

Comment: @Owen was right in his first comment, checkout my answer.